# matplotlib: different handletextpad values in the same legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following script:

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(8,7)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


### PLOT

for k in my_dict:

    x, y = my_dict[k][0], my_dict[k][1]
    ax1.plot(x, y, linewidth = 0, marker='o', markersize = 4)


X = np.logspace(0.3, 6.6)
ax1.plot(X, 2*X**(-2), linewidth = 2, c='k')

X = np.logspace(0.3, 7.7)
ax1.plot(X, 3*X**(-1.5), linewidth = 2, c='b')


ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax1.set_yscale('log')


## LEGEND


labels = ['$10^{-1} \, \\Delta_1^*$', '$\\Delta_1^*$',\
          '$10^{5/2} \, \\Delta_1^*$', '$10^3 \, \\Delta_1^*$',
         '$x^{-2}$', '$x^{-3/2}$']

curves = ax1.get_lines()
legend1 = ax1.legend([curves[0], curves[1], curves[2]],\
                     [labels[0], labels[1], labels[2]],\
                     loc=1, ncol=1, fancybox=False, shadow=False,\
                     framealpha=0.0, markerscale=2, fontsize=25, handletextpad=0.0)

legend2 = ax1.legend([curves[3], curves[4], curves[5]],\
                     [labels[3], labels[4], labels[5]],\
                     loc=3, ncol=1, fancybox=False, shadow=False,\
                     framealpha=0.0, markerscale=2, fontsize=25, handletextpad=0.0)




vp = legend1._legend_box._children[-1]._children[0]
for c in vp._children:
    c._children.reverse()
vp.align="right"


ax1.add_artist(legend1)
ax1.add_artist(legend2)


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The result is [image]

**The issue**: I use `handletextpad` in the legends, and that is because I need points and text to be very close. However the last two elements in the second legend are not points, but lines. They take more space then points and the text happens to be too close.

**I need to keep this distance between text and points while increasing the distance between  text and lines in the same legend**.

I tried with `handletextpad=[0.1, 0.5, 0.5]` and similar strategies, but I haven't been able to set individual values of `handletextpad`.

Another possibility would be to make separate legends and specifically one with only lines. This, however, would force me to manually positioning any legend very carefully and I'd rather not doing it. Also (I don't know if it can help), but I'd rather not replace

`plt.plot(x, y, linewidth = 0, markersize = 4)`

with

`plt.scatter(x, y)`.

Except for these two caveats, everything is welcome.